# jQuery loop through appended divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to build a nice effect of looping through photos but only worked when they were on the HTML code at start and not appended after.

Here goes the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        EmbedInit();
    });

function EmbedInit()
{
    // Init will be called when this page is loaded in the client.
    Start();

    var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
    i = 0;
    (function cycle() {
        divs.eq(i).fadeIn(800)
                  .delay(1000)
                  .fadeOut(800, cycle);
        i = ++i % divs.length;
    })();

    return;
}
```

And before you ask this is a work around for a software that starts by calling the `EmbedInit`so this part I can't touch. Just added the `$(document).ready(function())` to test it on the broswer first.

And now my `start()` function which is an ajax request and adds around 5 divs to my code like this:

```
function Start() {
    var row1 = '<div id="content-1"><div id="photo"><img width="170" src="img.jpg"></div><div class="Text">Text</div></div>';
    var row2 = '<div id="content-2"><div id="photo"><img width="170" src="img.jpg"></div><div class="Text">Text</div></div>';
    var row3 = '<div id="content-3"><div id="photo"><img width="170" src="img.jpg"></div><div class="Text">Text</div></div>';
    $('#main').append(row1);
    $('#main').append(row2);
    $('#main').append(row3);
};
```

Div Main is there and I can see the content on the page but the loop through divs is not ok. I guess it's something to do with divs being added dynamically because variable `divs` has always 0 length.

What should be the best approach to handle this?

Comment: Your code doesn't loop! Do you want to fadeIn the next div after the last div been fadeOut? Or all at the same time?

Comment: Yes  fadeIn the next div after the last div been fadeOut.

Comment: Is this fiddle is what you intend to have? https://jsfiddle.net/90xu717h/

Comment: All the element IDs in HTML are to be unique

Comment: @ub3rst4r, yes the multiple `photo` id's are bad, but would have no affect on this... and also likely just there as a copy paste example of what would be created with his ajax call

Comment: @RoylyanNikita yes it yes but I've seen you changed the `$(document).ready(function() {});` and that I can't do because that is native to the software.

Comment: @smerny I guess you are right and this seems to be the issue cause variable `divs` has length 0. You want me to paste the full code?

Comment: Typo in function name you call start() but the function is Start()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is `Start` with uppercase `S` not lowercas `s`.

```
function EmbedInit()
{
    // Here is the trouble maker
    Start();

    var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
    i = 0;
    function cycle() {
        divs.eq(i).fadeIn(800)
                  .delay(1000)
                  .fadeOut(800, cycle);
        i = (i + 1) % divs.length; // this is safer than ++i
    }
    cycle(); // call cycle normally (no need for Immediately Invoked Function Call)

    // return here has no meaning
}
```

**Working snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  EmbedInit();
});

function Start() {
  var row1 = '<div id="content-1"><div id="photo"><img width="170" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></div><div class="Text">Text</div></div>';
  var row2 = '<div id="content-2"><div id="photo"><img width="170" src="http://placehold.it/201x201"></div><div class="Text">Text</div></div>';
  var row3 = '<div id="content-3"><div id="photo"><img width="170" src="http://placehold.it/202x202"></div><div class="Text">Text</div></div>';
  $('#main').append(row1);
  $('#main').append(row2);
  $('#main').append(row3);
}

function EmbedInit() {
  // Here is the trouble maker
  Start();

  var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
    i = 0;

  function cycle() {
    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(800)
      .delay(1000)
      .fadeOut(800, cycle);
    i = (i + 1) % divs.length; // this is safer than ++i
  }
  cycle(); // call cycle normally (no need for Immediately Invoked Function Call)

  // return here has no meaning
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='main'></div>
```

Comment: @smerny Why? Explain!

Comment: Yes, I appreciate code seems more clean now but the question is that `var divs` seems to be the problem. It's not finding the elements, they don't even hide.

Comment: @rgomez it's `Start` not `start`. See the new updated answer!

Comment: That might have been a misstyping. I have te same problem if I do `console.log(divs)` I still see 0 length so it's not finding the divs.

Comment: Yes it is, I had another error on the code, bracket was on wrong place on my code. Thank you very much for your help @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: You're welcome! I did nothing really. But you're welcome!